# JSHINT Throws Syntax Error for If statement equation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if the `projectCount` is divisible by 4 and not by 5 then vice versa in an else if statement. My code compiles however jshint throws 15 syntax errors. How else would I structure this to remove those syntax errors?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if($(".projects li").hasClass("projectCols-30")) {
        var projectCount = $('.projectCols-30').length;

        if (projectCount % 4 = 0 && projectCount % 5 != 0) {
            alert("The total number of columns means there is always only 1 extra on a row");
        } else if (projectCount % 4 != 0 && projectCount % 5 = 0) {
            alert("The total number of columns means there is always only 2 extra on a row");
        }
    }
});
```

> Four warnings 5   Bad assignment. 5   Expected a conditional expression
>   and instead saw an assignment. 7  Bad assignment. 7   Expected a
>   conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.

After some edits, the following no longer throws syntax errors **Talg123** please post this as an answer as you fixed the problem in a comment.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if($(".projects li").hasClass("projectCols-30")) {
        var projectCount = $('.projectCols-30').length;

        if (projectCount % 4 === 0 && projectCount % 5 !== 0) {
            alert("The total number of columns means there is always only 1 extra on a row");
        } else if (projectCount % 4 !== 0 && projectCount % 5 === 0) {
            alert("The total number of columns means there is always only 2 extra on a row");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: projectCount % 4 = 0 && projectCount % 5 != 0
should be
projectCount % 4 == 0 && projectCount % 5 != 0

and
(projectCount % 4 != 0 && projectCount % 5 == 0)

Comment: Could you add the errors to your question?

Comment: Thanks @Talg123, please post as an answer as your comment was the original one that fixed the syntax's. Much appreciated.

Comment: `=` is for setting values, `==` and `===` are for comparison.

Comment: When I pass that through JS Hint it reports four warnings and one undeclared variable but no syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if($(".projects li").hasClass("projectCols-30")) {
    var projectCount = $('.projectCols-30').length;

    if (projectCount % 4 === 0 && projectCount % 5 !== 0) {
        alert("The total number of columns means there is always only 1 extra on a row");
    } else if (projectCount % 4 !== 0 && projectCount % 5 === 0) {
        alert("The total number of columns means there is always only 2 extra on a row");
    }
}
```

});

well basicly you need to compare with which means that u need to use ==\=== for equal and not to set your variable with =

Comment: Add comments about your code of "why" for this correction!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a single `=` to compare numbers, this is the assignment operator.
Write `projectCount % 4 == 0` or `projectCount % 4 === 0` instead.